# Running Google Analytics under play 2.2.1 on heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, google-analytics, playframework-2.0

I have created a test page on `heroku`: [Test Page](http://shrouded-bastion-7859.herokuapp.com/)

I have also added `Google Analytics`:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'shrouded-bastion-7859.herokuapp.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

As you can see in my site code, I have inserted this script in my plain `html` page.

In the play project I have implemented the sites as static html pages in the public folder.

However, on the Google analytics board it says that:

> Status: Tracking Not Installed

What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: In network tab (in Chrome) I see the `analytics.js` being loaded. So i think this just need some more time to 'sync' with Google, when did you created the analytics account?

Comment: @adis I created it around 5 hours ago...

Comment: any update today? Is it still 'not' showing up in GA?

Comment: @adis Thx for your reply! However, it still says in the GAE Admin Panel `Status: Tracking Not Installed`